# Using a refresh token to get a bot access token replaces the refresh token

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api, refresh-token

I am trying to convert my Slack app code to use bot refresh tokens rather than the old bot token when accessing the web client api.

I have been able to call the `https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access` endpoint both from Postman and using the Slack Webclient node.js module.

I am passing in my app's client id, client secret, my bot refresh token and a grant_type of `refresh_token`.

In both cases the Slack API responds with a new `access_token` but sometimes I also get a new `refresh_token` and I can't use my original refresh token to get more access tokens.

This doesn't seem correct;

I have stored the refresh token from the app OAuth web page in a secret store. Typically you would use the non-expiring refresh token to get access tokens as required.

Since Slack is also refreshing the `refresh_token` each time, I am unable to rely on the secret store and I will need to persist this refresh token in some other place, which is potentially insecure.

When the refresh token changes it also invalidates the `installation` object that I have persisted and I need to re-do the "Add to Slack" process to fix that.

Am I doing something wrong, such as using the wrong endpoint, or is the Slack API "broken"?

**Update & clarification**

Thanks for those in the comments who have pointed out that issuing a new refresh token is in the OAuth spec.

The reason that this is a problem for me is that I need bot access tokens in two places.  In one of those places the token refresh is handled by Slack's Bolt framework.  In the other I am handling token refresh myself.

Since a new refresh token is issued when the access token is refreshed, one of those two places no longer knows the "current" refresh token, so it fails next time it tries to refresh *its* access token.  Which one fails depends on which one refreshed the token.

The comment on the refresh token in the Slack OAuth page for the app says "never expires", but this is misleading as while it doesn't expire per-se, the value shown in the page does become invalid when a new access token is generated from it.

This is quite different behaviour from other "never expires" tokens such as the app client secret, which is only invalidated if you manually re-issue it in the settings page.

Prior to token rotation, slack apps used a non-expiring "Bot token" that could be used in multiple places.  It seems that you cannot get the exact behaviour with OAuth and token rotation.

Comment: "*This doesn't seem correct*". Hard to say without knowing how exactly you configured token rotation for your app, but assuming you read this: https://api.slack.com/authentication/rotation#refresh. You need to wire up logic to refresh the access token before `expires_in` transpires and store the new refresh tokens the same way you do access tokens. If you have enabled token rotation then new refresh tokens are expected and it is up to your app to store and use them correctly. What is the `installation` object and how is it invalidated by receiving new refresh tokens?

Comment: See the spec on refresh tokens: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-10.4. Specifically "*When client authentication is not possible, the
   authorization server SHOULD deploy other means to detect refresh token abuse.

   For example, the authorization server could employ refresh token rotation in which a new refresh token is issued with every access token refresh response.*"

Comment: In terms of token storage thats dependent upon your app but slack offers some nice guidelines in their documentation: https://api.slack.com/authentication/best-practices#safe_token_storage

Comment: Here's a basic implementation for refreshing an access token with an oauth API as express middleware. You *could* run this middleware for *any* API request to a resource. It simply stores the updated token set (access and refresh tokens) in the session store when detecting an expired access token. I was using Redis as the session store, but you might want to use a different approach like a scheduled job based on `expires_in` if store access is slower. https://gist.github.com/morganney/d667128bfb02d7dbc1a8fa4fed2b46d4

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is interesting that refresh token refresh is in the spec. It is just annoying.  User Access tokens are stored in Firestore as an encrypted string while the bot access token is just held in memory since the idea was they can be created as required from the refresh token. I can store the refresh token in Firestore too , but I have to solve the "bootstrap" problem as there is no simple way to get the initial refresh token into that store.  Currently the refresh token is held in a secret store and the value is passed into the container via an environment variable.

Comment: The other problem I can potentially see comes when my containers start to auto scale.  I handle access token expiry by tracking the returned `expires_in` but I think I have seen the case where getting a new access token causes the refresh token to change which invalidates other access tokens before they expire, but I need to confirm this. If this does happen then container "A" refreshing it's about-to-expire token could invalidate container "B"s access token before it expires.

Comment: Oh, and the "installation object" is an item that is provided by the slack Bolt framework when an admin uses the "add to slack" button. Your app needs to provide a method for storing and retrieving this object when requested by Slack's Bolt framework, and this is my real problem. The object isn't encrypted or anything, but it is meant to be somewhat opaque. You simply hand back what you were given when requested. Now you have me thinking, perhaps I can use this object to get my tokens if the Bolt framework is managing this.

Comment: "but sometimes I also get a new refresh_token"... if you ask for a refresh_token, you will always receive a refresh_token. Also this refresh_token will expire some day, and you need to request a new one. Is this your problem?

Comment: It is, but typically refresh tokens have a lifetime of days, or even months, often linked to the account and/or password change status of a user and you can get a new one by getting the user to re-auth. The Slack App Bot Token is the app's own identity that lets it message users, for example,  the "old" bot token was completely static. The new approach is a long-lived refresh token which you obtain from the app setup page that is used to obtain access tokens

Comment: My difficulty comes from now needing to create some service that coordinates the new refresh token amongst somewhat independent services when ideally they could just request their own, independent, access tokens having had the secret injected into their environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Codebling and @morganney pointed out, it is within the OAuth spec for a new refresh token to be issued alongside a new access token.

My problem arises because I need an access token in two separate parts of my app.  One part is using Slack's Bolt framework and the other isn't.  This leads to a potential for conflict where the refresh token is updated by one or the other parts of my app.

The solution is to leverage the Slack Bolt `InstallProvider` in the non-Bolt code in my app (This requires that the non-Bolt code can access the same `InstallationStore` implementation as the Bolt code).

Using the `InstallProvider` ensures that if a token refresh is required, the `InstallationStore` is always updated and a consistent set of tokens (refresh and access) is available to both parts of my app.

In the non-Bolt code I use the following to obtain an access token to call the Slack Web client:

```
const installer = new InstallProvider({
          clientId: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID!,
          clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET!,
          installationStore: new MyInstallationStore(),
          stateSecret: 'someSecret'
        })

const authorizeResult = await installer.authorize({
          isEnterpriseInstall: enterpriseId !== undefined,
          enterpriseId: enterpriseId,
          teamId: teamId
})

if (authorizeResult.botToken) {
    await this.webclient.chat.postMessage({
             channel: slackId,
             blocks: blocks,
             icon_emoji: `:wave:`,
             text: "Welcome message",
             token: authorizeResult.botToken,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong. It is, however, on-spec to re-issue refresh tokens.

The relevant section of the spec is [Section 1.5. Refresh Token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5). Step H says (emphasis mine):

> (H)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
> the refresh token, and if valid, issues a new access token (**and,
> optionally, a new refresh token**).

You'll unfortunately have to accommodate this behavior in your code. It's not clear why you cannot change values in your secret store (or why values that get updated cannot be stored in your secret store). Feel free to post some code if you'd like some suggestions

Comment: It's not that I *can't* change the value in my secret store. I can but it has security implications.  I am using Google Secret Manager and unfortunately the roles that can be assigned to a service account are "secret reader" and "secret admin", so if I want my service account to be able to update the secret there then I have to give it admin, which I don't want to do.  I can use a different storage method as I do with access tokens

Comment: The other problem is coordinating this refresh token update amongst  different services. Since the refresh token itself doesn't have an expiration time or interval, service instances that otherwise don't communicate now need to know that the refresh token has changed.  In theory,  they can get an error and re-fetch the refresh token from somewhere, but I use this token both in code I have written myself and via Slack's bolt framework. When my code causes a new refresh token to be minted, there is no way to tell bolt and vice-versa.

Comment: @Paulw11 ah ok I understand now about the secret store. As for refresh token expiry, we know that the refresh tokens are 1) valid for at least as long as the access token (and we have the expiry for the access token), 2) that the refresh token will be replaced at least once before the expiry time is up, since a request for a new access token will be made before expiry and a new refresh token will be issued.

Comment: I don't have all of the details of your setup, but you should be able to use webhooks to alert the Bolt code [[1](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#incoming_webhooks_programmatic)] [[2](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#posting_with_webhooks)]. Though if both components are (more or less) separate, perhaps they could use separate access tokens and not try to share?

Comment: The access tokens have a validity of 11 hours, but I am seeing refresh tokens replaced almost every time I request a new access token, which could be every few minutes as I restart during development; My service starts, uses the refresh token from the secret store to get an access token; This issues a new refresh token.  Next time my service starts the refresh token can't be used.  The components aren't sharing access tokens, but I need to share the refresh token so that. they can get their own access token.  It was when I implemented this that I discovered the refresh token problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 gotcha. I don't know if there's really going to be a 'solution' to this the way the app is set up. It sounds like you may have to change it such that it updates the refresh token every time, or change the setup completely. In my head, each component should be requesting its own access token from scratch every startup rather than relying on having a refresh token already in the store (which feels like a bit chicken-and-egg to me). Also, it feels like refresh and access tokens should be 1:1, so having a refresh token and using it to obtain multiple access tokens doesn't feel quite right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240427/discussion-between-paulw11-and-codebling).